# Non-parametric regression with constraints

Tags: r, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, spline, non-linear-regression

I wish to fit a non-parametric model (such as a spline, GAM, etc.) given data `x >= 0` and `f(x) >= 0`  imposing the following constraints:

```
f(0) = 0
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = b, 
max(f(x)) = b
```

[image: equations, same as listed above]

I would be okay assuming a monotonically increasing function (and thereby dispel with the third condition), but wish to make no assumption about its concavity (excepting as required to satisfy the second condition).

`b` is obviously a parameter, so an alternative way of writing the second condition would be

```
\lim_{x \to \infty} d f(x)/ d x = 0
```

[image: equations, same as listed above]

I wish to (1) estimate `b` and its confidence interval, and (2) predict `f(x)` for non-observed values of `x` (interpolated and extrapolated beyond data).

Suggestions for how to implement in Matlab, R or Mathematica appreciated.

Two datasets to illustrate:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 500
xmax <- 25

x <- sort(runif(n)) * xmax
f1 <- function(x){ b * x^c / (a + x^c) }
f2 <- function(x){ b * (1 - exp(-(1/a)*x^c))}

a <- xmax
b <- 1.5*xmax
c <- 1.5

y1 <- sapply(f1(x), function(x){rpois(1, x)})
y2 <- sapply(f2(x), function(x){rpois(1, x)})

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

plot(x, y1, xlim = c(0, 1.5 * xmax))
curve(f1(x), add = TRUE)

plot(x, y2, xlim = c(0, 1.5 * xmax))
curve(f2(x), add = TRUE)
```

[image: plots]

**EDIT (*progress*)**

I've made progress using constrained B-splines with the [cobs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobs/index.html) package.  Using `pointwise`, I can implement the first constraint, `f(0)=0`, exactly as desired and can implement `d f(x) / d x = 0` at an arbitrary value of `x`.

However, I do need to specify that value of `x` where `d f(x) / d x = 0`.  Below, I do so by specifying that it occurs at a value of `x = bmax * max(x)` (though in playing around with the degree to which the simulated data saturate, it's clear that it's still possible for `d f(x) / d x = 0` to begin at values of `x` less than `bmax * max(x)` as well).

```
y <- y1
spfit <- cobs::cobs(x, y,
          constraint = 'increase',
          pointwise = rbind(
             c(0, 0, 0),            # force through origin
             c(2, bmax * max(x), 0) # force df/dx = 0 at bmax*max(x)
           ) )
```

With this approach I no longer need to estimate `b` directly (i.e. I can instead use `predict()` and evaluate `spfit` at `bmax * max(x)`).

The question now is: *How can I make `bmax` a free parameter?*

Comment: You might be able to do this by appropriately transforming x and y. If in R you fit `lm(qlogis(x/b) ~ splines::ns(log(x), k))`, then all you have to do is constrain the slope to be negative at the left edge of the data (so that `b*plogis(lim (log(x) \to -\infty)) = 0)` and positive at the right edge of the data (so that `b*plogis(lim(log(x) \to \infty)) = b))` (since extrapolations of natural splines beyond the range of the data are linear).  Any chance we could have a [mcve] (i.e., some input x and y values) to try out?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I've added two hypothetical datasets.  In particular, note that `b` can be less than `max(y)` --- I assume you meant to write `qlogis(y/b)` --- and that I mis-represented my desire in stating that I only wished to interpolate.  Rather, I wish to extrapolate beyond the data as well. (I've edited the original post to reflect this.)

Comment: Having a parametric model would greatly "ease" extrapolation (and may even be necessary for all I know/understand), but I am hoping for a means to assume a continuation of a sufficiently smoothed local shape beyond the data (subject to the desired limit constraint).  I need to spend time with the `ns()` function; it's not clear to me how to constrain the slopes as you suggested.